# How i can join two segments of curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I want to create it like one solid pipe. How to fix that?

I think that problem is in segment's which are not connected.

If I want to press <kbd>F</kbd> - *Cannot make segments*.

[image]

Comment: The GIF is too low resolution to make out your issue. Please edit the question and describe it in words.

Comment: Nice touch on the text.

Comment: Curve can't connect in right way. You can see that pipes are not connected good. I think that's the wrong connected segment's but i can't connect them together. :(